# Include same header file for all clion projects

Tags: c++, ide, settings, clion

I am currently solving many similar tasks that use a header file written by me, in which, for example, there is a vector output operator, and so on. I would like this header to be added to each of my new projects automatically(or same setting like create from template), so that I don't have to do it manually. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a library (could be a header-only one) that includes all those headers. And make it available through the path variable.

But you always need to add at least one include in the file in which you want to use it.